# DF Player Mini on Arduino Uno Not Playing

Tags: arduino, ide, arduino-uno

I have a problem which is driving me crazy .I want to use dfmini player to play Songs on the arduino and output it on a 8 ohm 0.5W Speaker , and nothing is working .I am using the DFRobotDFPlayerMini Library code as is but nothing is playing at all .Here is a photo of my connections.
[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzjpK.jpg)
I apologize if my photo is not clear as i don't have time for software drawing, and i didnt use a breadboard as actually the DF Player is slightly bigger than the holes.
The Arduino Pins Used is 11,10  and 5V and 2 Pins for the GND
Here is the Code of the DFRobot Library used as is .
The Files on the SD Card are in a folder mp3 and written as 0001.mp3 0002.mp3 ..etc
When i Connect and try it out . The Blue Led on MP3 Player doesn't light up , and on the Serial Monitor Baud 115200 :
DFRobot DFPlayer Mini
DFRobot DFPlayer Mini Demo
Initializing DFPlayer ... (May take 3~5 seconds)
DFPlayer Mini online.
and on Serial Monitor Baud 9600:
⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮ܙf⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮
Would be very thankful if anyone can solve this problem.

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
#include "DFRobotDFPlayerMini.h"

SoftwareSerial mySoftwareSerial(10, 11); // RX, TX
DFRobotDFPlayerMini myDFPlayer;
void printDetail(uint8_t type, int value);

void setup()
{
  mySoftwareSerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(F("DFRobot DFPlayer Mini Demo"));
  Serial.println(F("Initializing DFPlayer ... (May take 3~5 seconds)"));
  
  if (!myDFPlayer.begin(mySoftwareSerial, false)) {  //Use softwareSerial to communicate with mp3.
    Serial.println(F("Unable to begin:"));
    Serial.println(F("1.Please recheck the connection!"));
    Serial.println(F("2.Please insert the SD card!"));
    while(true){
      delay(0); // Code to compatible with ESP8266 watch dog.
    }
  }
  Serial.println(F("DFPlayer Mini online."));
  
  myDFPlayer.volume(10);  //Set volume value. From 0 to 30
  myDFPlayer.play(1);  //Play the first mp3
}

void loop()
{
  static unsigned long timer = millis();
  
  if (millis() - timer > 3000) {
    timer = millis();
    myDFPlayer.next();  //Play next mp3 every 3 second.
  }
  
  if (myDFPlayer.available()) {
    printDetail(myDFPlayer.readType(), myDFPlayer.read()); //Print the detail message from DFPlayer to handle different errors and states.
  }
}

void printDetail(uint8_t type, int value){
  switch (type) {
    case TimeOut:
      Serial.println(F("Time Out!"));
      break;
    case WrongStack:
      Serial.println(F("Stack Wrong!"));
      break;
    case DFPlayerCardInserted:
      Serial.println(F("Card Inserted!"));
      break;
    case DFPlayerCardRemoved:
      Serial.println(F("Card Removed!"));
      break;
    case DFPlayerCardOnline:
      Serial.println(F("Card Online!"));
      break;
    case DFPlayerUSBInserted:
      Serial.println("USB Inserted!");
      break;
    case DFPlayerUSBRemoved:
      Serial.println("USB Removed!");
      break;
    case DFPlayerPlayFinished:
      Serial.print(F("Number:"));
      Serial.print(value);
      Serial.println(F(" Play Finished!"));
      break;
    case DFPlayerError:
      Serial.print(F("DFPlayerError:"));
      switch (value) {
        case Busy:
          Serial.println(F("Card not found"));
          break;
        case Sleeping:
          Serial.println(F("Sleeping"));
          break;
        case SerialWrongStack:
          Serial.println(F("Get Wrong Stack"));
          break;
        case CheckSumNotMatch:
          Serial.println(F("Check Sum Not Match"));
          break;
        case FileIndexOut:
          Serial.println(F("File Index Out of Bound"));
          break;
        case FileMismatch:
          Serial.println(F("Cannot Find File"));
          break;
        case Advertise:
          Serial.println(F("In Advertise"));
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Even When i change the Serial.begin to (9600) this doesn't solve the issue

Comment: No it doesn't print these questions mark , however this still doesn't Solve the Issue.Appreciate your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as it appeared was in the Arduino Cable , Make Sure that the cable itself is working properly

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```c
if (!myDFPlayer.begin(mySoftwareSerial, false))
```

to:

```c
if (!myDFPlayer.begin(mySoftwareSerial, true, false))
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30772801)